# Larger iTunes Search API Images

Tags: image, api, itunes

The iTunes search API provides album images for each artist's albums. The image sizes provided by the API are fairly small (100x100 was the largest). Playing with the urls I was able to write a script to access larger images. The largest I have been able to find was 225x225. Does anyone know of a larger size available, preferably around 500x500 or larger?

Thanks.

PS: the urls for the images are in this format, and the numbers at the end represent the image size.

```
http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/038/Music/db/09/6a/mzi.fivmbmtu.225x225-75.jpg
```

Comment: 600x600 used to be available but lately has just returned an error (a cdn error, not a 404 mind you) for certain apple servers (a1, a4, etc). 170x170 also works but thanks for the 225x225 tip.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should be able to get 600x600.

Check this out :

small : http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/038/Music/db/09/6a/mzi.fivmbmtu.225x225-75.jpg

large : http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/038/Music/db/09/6a/mzi.fivmbmtu.600x600-75.jpg

A simple string replace should do the trick.

Cheers,

Comment: Cheers, thank you. A bit too late now, since the project has been completed for a while now, but this may be helpful for future reference or for others.

Answer (score 0):

The artworkUrl512 or artworkUrl100 are the highest ones 512*512 and 1024*1024

Comment: That's for app icons dude.